# How to read and write a cookie using redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a react app where I just implemented redux, I need redux to add items to a list, and the list must be accessible from different components. So my code in the reducer is this:

```
switch (type) {
    case ADD_ITEM:
        return {
            ...state,
            items: [...state.items, itemId]
        };
    default:
        return state;
}
```

This works just fine. Now I want to use a cookie to save the items, but I am not sure where and how (using a library or just setCookie in JS) to implement it.

Also when I reload the page I would like to read the cookie and update the redux state so they are always in sync, how can I achieve this?

thanks

Comment: Interactions with cookies would count as side effects and should probably be handled in some kind of middleware function.  That being said, I'd tell you to not reinvent the wheel and try to leverage something like [redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you to avoid side effects in reducers since reducers are meant to be pure functions. Use subscribe function instead, so you will have access to current state.

```
store.subscribe(() => {
   const state = store.getState();
   document.cookie = `items=${state['yourItemsKey']}`;
});
```

And about reading the cookie and setting state - you could make a simple logic in your e.g. `index.js` file:

```
const items = // parse cookies to get list of items
if (items) {
   store.dispatch(action, items);
}
```

Comment: sorry I don't understand how to integrate this with my code...

Comment: @user3174311 You must be importing somewhere redux and setting the store, right? Probably in `index.js` file. In that place you should use both of these functions, modifying them slightly to fit your logic